# Approval Process for OrderItem Object in Salesforce?

Tags: approval-process, orderitem

Does anyone know how to create a approval process for Object Order Product(orderitem) object in Salesforce?I can't find the names in the list of objects in the approval definition screen or find any relevant documentation associated with this object about approval process

Answer (score 2):

Approval process is not available currently on OpportunityLineItem,QuoteLineItem and OrderLineItem.

Depending upon requirement, a rollup summary field and Approval Process on parent object may suffice.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982204/how-to-create-approval-process-for-opportunity-products